# Unable to use transactions on db2 with ibm400

Tags: sql, t-sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to combine dynamic update and select on `db2`.

Everything works fine until I'm applying transactioning (i.e. `commit`,`rollback` or `savepoint`)

For instance, executing very basic command
`SAVEPOINT SAVEPOINT1 ON ROLLBACK RETAIN CURSORS`
gives `COMMIT, ROLLBACK, or SAVEPOINT not valid.`

Same effect for simple `commit` and others.

Can anybody explain why I'm unable to execute this commands and how to fix it?
Google shows only ibm docs with examples that are not applicable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent to SQL Server Transactions in DB2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809136/what-is-the-equivalent-to-sql-server-transactions-in-db2)

Comment: where are you trying to run such commands?  What error message to you get?

Comment: What isolation level are you using?  None?

Answer (score 1):

You Library (schema) where you have your tables must be journalised. Look this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/rzaki/rzakisetupjrnexmp.htm) for create your journalisation

Comment: Actually, you don't necessarily have to journal all tables in a library, although  it may often be desirable, and it may make things simpler to manage.  If the library was created by SQL `CREATE SCHEMA` then the infrastructure has already been built for you, and any tables created in that library will be journalled for you by default. If you've built the infrastructure manually, DB2 will automatically journal new tables in that library by default if you set up a data area [QDFTJRN](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/rzaki/rzakiautostrjrnl.htm)