# IBM db2 to SQL server conversion of scripts

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, db2

What is the equivalent of 'commit' in IBM DB2 scripts in SQL server ? Will 'GO' in sql server scripts give the same functionality ?

Comment: The command is unnecessary in sql server.

Comment: Can you pls elaborate ?

Comment: `COMMIT` is a standard SQL statement; it is also supported by SQL Server.

Comment: @mustaccio i know that. But, in my ibm db2 script which i am trying to convert, it doesn't have begin and end transactions like we have in sql server scripts if at all we use commit. Hence, I am trying to understand is there a difference in ibm db2 ? Will it not commit by default ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent to SQL Server Transactions in DB2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809136/what-is-the-equivalent-to-sql-server-transactions-in-db2)

Answer (score 0):

It depends both on the DB2 script concerned and how that DB2-script gets executed (i.e. which options are effective at the time of execution). DB2-scripts can *either* have auto-commit enabled (this is the default for scripts executed by the DB2 CLP, no explicit commit needed, commit happens automatically after each statement), or disabled (in which case the script must then use explicit commits) , and this can be changed on the fly within the script also.